# How deploy a Ruby on Rails app on Windows Azure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

Does Windows Azure Platform allow to deploy a ruby on rails app?
If yes, in which kind of service? It's a SAAS like Heroku or it is a IAAS?

Thank you!

Comment: Azure Web Sites? or Azure normal server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used...

**For Azure Virtual Machine:**

1. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/other/tutorials/ruby-on-rails-nopublish/
2. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/SVC03 [video]
3. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-ruby-rails-web-app-linux/

**For Azure Web Sites:**

Not yet.

Comment: Web Sites does also support Node.JS and Python, while indeed they don't support Ruby, don't limit them to just .NET and PHP, as this is not the case!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Linux VPS on Azure.